# Jekyll site with several languages

Tags: jekyll, liquid, multilingual

I have a site that i am writing in spanish but now i want write this also in english.
I use Jekyll and the theme "Skinny Bones", and i modified a little the code, but i found a problem and i hope that you can help me.

I set a new variable in _config.yml called lang that at first is set at "es" (spanish).

After, i changed the next code:

```
{% for post in site.categories.articles %}
 {% include post-grid.html %}
{% endfor %}
```

by this:

```
 <!-- español -->
 {% if site.lang == 'es' %}
  {% for post in site.categories.media %}
   {% if post.lang == 'es' %}
    {% include post-grid.html %}
   {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}

<!-- inglés -->
{% if site.lang == 'en' %}
 {% for post in site.categories.media %}
  {% if post.lang == 'en' %}
    {% include post-grid.html %}
  {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

On this form if the variable was set with "en" in _config.yml and the post in media folder are a post with lang set with "en" it will show.

This work fine, when i change the _config.yml and set the variable with "en " or "es" and i rebuild project in my local host the change happens and only it show the post in the idiom correct.

But my problem is this: ¿How change a variable on _config.yml when the server are running?
My idea is  make a button to change this variable in some place of page.

I saw the function 
{% assign site.lang='es' %}
but not working when I do executing this in a code.

Well, i know that this isn't a complicated problem but i don't find the solution.

Thanks you so much for your help.

If you want see it, this is my [repo page](https://github.com/juanAFernandez/juanAFernandez.github.io).

Answer (score 0):

> ¿How change a variable on _config.yml when the server are running?

I'm pretty sure you can't. Have you looked at this plugin?

https://github.com/screeninteraction/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin

Comment: Yes, I tried, but in my page I use a theme and is very difficult adapt it with the plugin, at least for my.
If I don't use the _config.yml file but I use another this will be possible?

Comment: "If I don't use the _config.yml file but I use another this will be possible?" I don't quite understand that part. Do you mean "use a method different than the config.yml"? I think that's what you'll have to do, but I suspect it would involve a plugin. Is there a plugin which is less complex than the one listed above?